# SlickGrid: sorting after reordering doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

In SlickGrid you can enable row reordering (drag and drop). See http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example9-row-reordering.html

My problem is that once I reorder a row (e.g. put row 3 above row 1) I can't sort the entries anymore. If a column is named "date" and I click on that column, nothing happens. On the other hand, if I do *not* reorder the rows manually and then sort by column, it works.

I don't mind that the "sort by column" will destroy my manual order. I just want to keep the option to sort it by column after the reorder.

Any tips are appreciated.

(I am using SlickGrid because there's a nice fork which features sticky rows/columns. I haven't found this feature elsewhere, so it's my only option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the grid is manually reordered the function subscribed to `moveRowsPlugin.onMoveRows` is executed. This function is calling `grid.setData(data)` to update the reordered rows onto the grid. Calling `grid.setData(data)` overrides the DataView and directly sets the data on the grid. Updates made to the DataView (e.g. sorting) are therefore no longer reflected on the grid.

To resolve this change `grid.setData(data)` to `dataView.setItems(data)` in the function subscribed to `moveRowsPlugin.onMoveRows` (line 364 of the inline JavaScript). I'd also recommend clearing the sort fields so the sort indicator is removed.

```
//Set updated data in DataView
dataView.setItems(data);

//Clear sort columns
grid.setSortColumns([]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!